# Как правильно получать данные компонентов из чанков в October CMS?

Tags: php, october

Изучаю готовый проект на October CMS и увидел интересную вещь относительно получения ссылки на массив product.

```
{% partial "product" product=this.controller.vars.data.product %}
```

Вкратце: имеется плагин Х, в котором есть компонент `Essence`, в котором подготавливаются данные для отображения на странице товара.
В частности, ниже представлен кусок кода с искомым `$data` из `this.controller.vars.data.product` (лишнее убрано для наглядности и к вопросу отношения не имеет):

```
public function find()
    $data['product'] = $this->getPreparedProduct($data['id']);                       
    $result = array(
    "type" => "product",
    "data" => $data
    );
return $result;
```

Вопрос заключается в чем: насколько правильно получать данные через `this.controller.vars.data.product` - это нормальный подход или костыль? 
Почему я подумал, что так быть не должно - имеется `$result`, который явно куда-то возвращается и который можно/нужно считывать традиционным способом, почему здесь искомые данные получаются из целого списка переменных контроллера - не понимаю.

Если можно, дайте ссылку на доки, где это прописано, на официальных доках я этого не увидел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.controller.vars.data.product - необязателен для получения нужных данных, вполне достаточно data.product.